# Blackberry WebWorks and the "Hardware Back Button"

Tags: blackberry, jquery-mobile, cordova, back-button, blackberry-webworks

i have problem with the "hardware back button" and Blackberry Webworks.

I'm using jquery mobile to create a phonegap application for Blackberry WebWorks (Smartphone version). 
When i have a link in my page like:

```
<a href="#" onclick="history.back()"></a>
```

everything works fine.

But when i use the WebWorks API to hook the "Hardware Back Button" like this

```
blackberry.system.event.onHardwareKey(blackberry.system.event.KEY_BACK,
function() {
   history.back();
   return false;
});
```

My app is just closed. (I tested on 9800 OS6 Simulator, and real device 9300 Curve 3G with OS6)

It's also strange when I modify the function to:

```
blackberry.system.event.onHardwareKey(blackberry.system.event.KEY_BACK,
function() {
   alert('Debug');
   return false;
});
```

then my app will not be closed (which should be correct)

So the problem is the calling "history.back()" inisde the onHardwareKey handler function.

Can anyone help me further?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Adding this to config.xml worked for me:

```
<feature id="blackberry.system.event" version="1.0.0"/>
```